# Erro: Undefined index

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este codigo e da-me o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: ID in

```
<?
require('../members/inc/config.php');
require('../lib/framework.php');

// load the configuration file.
$newsid = $_GET['ID'];

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id = '$newsid' ");
while($myrow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

               //now print the results:
               echo "<b>Title: ";
               echo $myrow['Title'];
               echo "</b><br>On: <i>";
               echo $myrow['Date'];
               echo $myrow['Embed'];
               echo "</i><hr align=left width=160>";
               echo $myrow['Hour'];

               // Now print the options to (Read,Edit & Delete the news)
               echo "<br><a href=\"testonho.php?newsid=$myrow[ID]\">Read More...</a>
                || <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$myrow[ID]\">Edit</a>
                 || <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$myrow[ID]\">Delete</a><br><hr>";

             }//end of loop

?>
```

Já tive a ver outras questões relacionadas com este erro aqui no **StackOverflow** e não encontrei realmente o que pretendia. Gostaria de uma ajuda para a resolução para este meu problema :s

Comment: nao me mostra nada..

Comment: O erro acontece na linha do `$_GET`? de `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Sim, na linha 6, esta: `$newsid = $_GET['ID'];`

Comment: Poderia colocar o resultado do `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Ja fiz isso e nao aparece nada.. Nenhum resultado..

Comment: Poderia colocar o html da vem esse `$_GET`, geralmente é um link ou um `<form>`

Comment: É esta mesmo, é suspoto eu chamar o script pelo link assim: `?newsid=ID_DA_NOTICIA`

Comment: Então você deveria chamar `$newsid = $_GET['newsid']` no lugar de `$newsid = $_GET['ID']`.

Comment: Isto resolveu o meu erro, mas nao seleciona apenas o id que selecionei.. :ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que seu código não está expresando a sua idea é exibir apenas um registro, use clausula WHERE no select.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '$newsid' ORDER BY id");
```

Para evitar o sql injection use prepared statements, não muda muito o código, uma etapa é adicionada ao processo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM news '; 

 if(!empty($newsid){// caso tenha um id exibe somente ele
    $sql .= ' WHERE id = ? ORDER BY id';
 }    

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($newsid)); // aqui faz o bind da interrogação com $newsid
$itens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //retorna todas as linhas de uma vez.

foreach($itens as $myrow){
   echo ....
}
```

Para receber parâmetros pela url, você precisa usar o mesmo nome definido no link, ex: seusite.com?newsid=ID_DA_NOTICIA, você deve chamar assim

```
 $newsid = $_GET['newsid'];
```

e não `$_GET['ID']` Pois a string `ID` não foi definida no link.

Comment: Muito obrigado colega, será possivel ajudar-me a adaptar o codigo contra ataque de SQL Injection? Agradecia !

Comment: Apercebi-me agora que se nao colocar o `?newsid=NUMERO` nao aparece a lista das noticias, pode ajudar-me? :ss

Answer (score 2):

Tem um erro em `$myrow[ID]` nas três linhas de *links* que formam o HTML. O correto deve ser `$myrow['ID']`. E precisa encapsular entre chaves por ser uma expressão complexa. Assim:

```
echo "<br><a href=\"testonho.php?newsid={$myrow['ID']}\">Read More...</a>
            || <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid={$myrow['ID']}\">Edit</a>
             || <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid={$myrow['ID']}\">Delete</a><br><hr>";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/UndefinedIndex.php).

Com a informação nova passada em comentário de como a primeira chamada está sendo feita fica claro que precisa de mais uma mudança. A linha 6 precisa ser trocada para:

```
$newsid = $_GET['newsid'];
```

Além disto, tem uma bela vulnerabilidade que pode permitir [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101) mas não relacionado com o problema relatado.

Comment: não é isso, isso está bem, é mmesmo na linha numero `6` :ss

Comment: Pode ajudar-me a ter uma melhor segurança? Contra SQL Injection?

Comment: Só agora você está falando em linha 6. deveria ter colocado na pergunta. Se é isto, então quando você está chamando este *script* não tem nenhum campo com nome `ID`sendo passado para ele através do GET. Com relação a segurança você precisaria abrir outra pergunta para deixar organizado, se fora uma pergunta bem específica. Já existe uma canônica sobre o assunto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/101

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5xwddf Tenho o campo ID..

Comment: Isto não mostra nada útil para resolver o problema. Edite sua pergunta e coloque o HTML da página que chama este *script*.

Comment: É esta mesmo, é suspoto eu chamar o script pelo link assim: `?newsid=ID_DA_NOTICIA`

Comment: Mude o que eu passei para você e veja se resolve.

Comment: Já mudei e agora só da a mensagem de erro, nem aparece a listagem das noticias todas. Antes aparecia o erro no topo e a listagem das noticias.. Agora somente aparece isso: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in `

Comment: Adicionei informações, veja se resolve. Se não resolver vai complicar sem ver como chega nesta página. Porque se é ela mesma que chama ela você tem um problema do ovo e a galinha. Você preciso do `ID` para gerar esta página corretamente. E só gerando ela corretamente é que você terá o `ID` necessário. Não tem como resolver isto se não houver outro trecho chamando ela e resolvendo o início disto.